# `h2o.cbind` accepts only of H2OFrame objects - R

Tags: r, machine-learning, h2o, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to ensemble a random forest with logistic regresion with H2O in R. However, an error messages appears in the following code:

```
> localH2O = h2o.init()
    Successfully connected to http://137.0.0.1:43329/ 

    R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
        H2O cluster uptime:         3 hours 11 minutes 
        H2O cluster version:        3.2.0.3 
        H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_toshiba_jvd559 
        H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
        H2O cluster total memory:   0.97 GB 
        H2O cluster total cores:    4 
        H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
        H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 

    > 
    > # defining the training data and set data for H2O

    > 
    > training_frame <- as.h2o(localH2O, muestra.fullarbol)
      |=========================================================================================| 100%
    > validation_frame <- as.h2o(localH2O, test.fullarbol)
      |=========================================================================================| 100%
    > 
    > yn <- "ex"
    > xn <- names(datafullarbol[,-c(1,2,3,9,10,11,12,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,29,31,32,33,34,35,36,47)])
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > 
    > learner <- c("h2o.glm.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper")
    > metalearner <- "SL.glm"
    > family <- "binomial"
    > 
    > fit <- h2o.ensemble(x=xn, y=yn,training_frame = training_frame, family = family, 
    + learner = learner, metalearner = metalearner,cvControl = list(V = 5))
      |=========================================================================================| 100%
    [1] "Cross-validating and training base learner 1: h2o.glm.wrapper"
      |=========================================================================================| 100%
    [1] "Cross-validating and training base learner 2: h2o.randomForest.wrapper"
      |=========================================================================================| 100%
    Error in h2o.cbind(predlist) : 
      `h2o.cbind` accepts only of H2OFrame objects
```

Apperently my parameters are given correctly , but as you see, the message: `h2o.cbind accepts only of H2OFrame objects appears`. What could be the reason of the error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be using either an older version of the h2o or h2oEnsemble package.  The object class of an H2O data frame used to be called `H2OFrame` and now it's just called `Frame`, and `h2o.cbind` is looking for for an object of type, `H2OFrame`.

You can fix this by updating your h2o and h2oEnsemble packages to the latest version as follows:

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) {remove.packages("h2o") }

# Now we download, install and initialize the latest stable release of the *h2o* package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/5/R")))
library(h2o)
```

Then update your h2oEnsemble as follows:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")
```

You can always find the latest stable (or bleeding edge) version of H2O at http://h2o.ai/download/.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Erin L :)

Comment: Please do **not use answers to ask** for reply from the questioner, use comments instead;

Comment: Thanks, I will update my answer so it does not ask for a reply.  This solution should fix the problem.