# h2oensemble Error in value[[3L]](cond) : argument "training_frame" must be a valid H2O H2OFrame or id

Tags: r, cran, h2o, ensemble-learning

While trying to run the example on H2OEnsemble found on http://learn.h2o.ai/content/tutorials/ensembles-stacking/index.html from within Rstudio, I encounter the following error:

> Error in value[3L] : 
>         argument "training_frame" must be a valid H2O H2OFrame or id

after defining the ensemble

```
fit <- h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y, 
                    training_frame = train, 
                     family = family, 
                     learner = learner, 
                     metalearner = metalearner,
                     cvControl = list(V = 5, shuffle = TRUE))
```

I installed the latest version of both `h2o` and `h2oEnsemble` but the issue remains. I have read here [`h2o.cbind` accepts only of H2OFrame objects - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070159/h2o-cbind-accepts-only-of-h2oframe-objects-r) that the naming convention in `h2o` changed over time, but I assume by installing the latest version of both this should not be any longer the issue.

Any suggestions?

```
library(readr)
library(h2oEnsemble)  # Requires version >=0.0.4 of h2oEnsemble
library(cvAUC)  # Used to calculate test set AUC (requires version >=1.0.1 of cvAUC)
localH2O <-  h2o.init(nthreads = -1)  # Start an H2O cluster with nthreads = num cores on your machine





# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into R
train <- h2o.importFile("http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~ledell/data/higgs_10k.csv")
test <- h2o.importFile("http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~ledell/data/higgs_test_5k.csv")
y <- "C1"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)
family <- "binomial"

#For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])  
test[,y] <- as.factor(test[,y])


# Specify the base learner library & the metalearner
learner <- c("h2o.glm.wrapper", "h2o.randomForest.wrapper", 
               "h2o.gbm.wrapper", "h2o.deeplearning.wrapper")
metalearner <- "h2o.deeplearning.wrapper"


# Train the ensemble using 5-fold CV to generate level-one data
# More CV folds will take longer to train, but should increase performance
fit <- h2o.ensemble(x = x, y = y, 
                    training_frame = train, 
                    family = family, 
                    learner = learner, 
                    metalearner = metalearner,
                    cvControl = list(V = 5, shuffle = TRUE))
```

Comment: Interestingly using the wrappers like h2o.randomForest.wrapper works. all other h2o statements also work, but as soon as you use the h2o.ensemle the code returns this error. It has something to do with a check on the frame. When I have time a bit later today I will create a jira issue.

Comment: @phiver thanks a lot. Could it be related to this? "It looks like you may be using either an older version of the h2o or h2oEnsemble package. The object class of an H2O data frame used to be called H2OFrame and now it's just called Frame, and h2o.cbind is looking for for an object of type, H2OFrame."  is one of the comments to the cbind issue in the second link

Comment: issue opened in [Jira](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-2481). It is already being picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug was recently introduced by a bulk find/replace change of a class name made to the h2o R code.  The change was inadvertently applied to the ensemble code folder as well (where we currently have manual instead of automatic tests -- soon to be automatic to prevent this sort of thing).  I've fixed the bug.

To fix, reinstall the h2oEnsemble package from GitHub:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")
```

Thanks for the report!  For a quicker response, post bugs and questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2ostream